# Graphs disabled n Tableau Desktop

Tags: graph, tableau-desktop

I am putting fields in columns and rows in my Tableau desktop but I don't why the graphs are all disabled from both right and left side. Only text table it is showing s where I am I going wrong in the process?

I did watch some youtube video but I still could not get the error. I want to try out different graphs but all are disabled. I have even placed fields in the columns and rows.